# You have an error in your SQL syntax - pymysql

Tags: python, sql, pymysql

Думаю ошибка глупая, заранее спасибо за ответ

```
id = message.from_user.id
        skin_name = data_return[1]
        price = data_return[0][1:]+"$"

        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            insert_query = f'INSERT INTO `user` (id, skin_name, price) VALUES ({id}, {skin_name}, {price});'
            cursor.execute(insert_query)
            connection.commit()
```

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'кейс #3, 0.96$)' at line 1")

Comment: `print(insert_query)` -> ?? Ну и сообщение об ошибке следует цитировать **полностью**.

Comment: Никогда не используй ф-строки в запросах

Comment: @Akina да там 100% тект без кавычек

Comment: @eri Скорее всего... но надо же иметь что-то материальное, куда потыкать...

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Можно просто написать ответ как подставлять значения через вопросики. Это решит и ошибку автора и поможет избежать других

Answer (score 1):

```py
id_ = message.from_user.id
skin_name = data_return[1]
price = data_return[0][1:] + "$"
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(insert_query, "INSERT INTO `user` (id, skin_name, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?);", (id_, skin_name, price))
    connection.commit()
```